# Vue - change state of another component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need to update the isHidden value to true.
My code divided in this componets:

// Profile.vue

```
<UserData
  v-bind:user_billing="user_billing"
  v-bind:user_profile="user_profile"
  ></UserData>
   <div class="col-12 px-0 my-3">
       <button @hide="hide"
               type="button"
               v-on:click="saveBillingData"
               class="btn btn-link color-link-ci btn-custom-hover border-0 rounded-pill pl-0">
                        Salva
       </button>
```

and // UserData.vue

```
<template>
  <form v-on:change="enableSave()"
...
methods: {

 enableSave(){
// here i want change the isHidden status to false

}
```

how I can change the state? i've tried with this.$parent / $children , but endpoint is not correct.

Comment: Besides what others have said, I'd warn that state is very dangerous. State is the concept that you save something. It's dangerous because you split your program in time, it becomes before and after. State can mismatch, state can be null. Ugh. But, we still need state. Thus, check out state management patterns. For vue, there's a very good and very tiny library called vuex. Check it out. It abstracts your problem out so you don't change state of another component. Instead all components read from and write into the same state (called store). Cheers and best of luck

Comment: See https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/ and the 'try this lesson on scrimba' (that's free, even though it looks like an ad)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Custom Events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) to fire an event from the child to the parent as follows:

1. In the parent (Profile):

```
<UserData
v-bind:user_billing="user_billing"
v-bind:user_profile="user_profile"
@hide="hide"
>
</UserData>
<button v-if="!isHidden"
        type="button" 
        v-on:click="saveBillingData"
        class="btn btn-link color-link-ci btn-custom-hover border-0 rounded-pill pl-0"
>
     Salva
</button>
```

```
methods:{
     hide(val){
          this.isHidden = val;
     }
}
```

2. In the child (UserData):

```
enableSave(){
     this.$emit("hide",false);
}
```

Comment: enableSave() is called, but hide(val) not, and console.log inside hide() give no print

Comment: Did you add this: ``@hide="hide"`` to the component?

Comment: yes, <button @hide="hide"
                              type="button"

Comment: It should be written in the Profile: ``<UserData ..></UserData>`` as above

Comment: I need to hide only Submit button, not all the UserData :(

Comment: There is no submit button in the question. Please add all the code or link to a fiddle

Comment: I updated the answer to hide the button if ``isHidden`` is true

Answer (score 0):

You can emit [events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names) in the child component and react to it in the parent component.

`this.$emit('change-hidden', !this.isHidden);`

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const UserData = Vue.component('user-data', {
  template: '<button @click="enableSave">Change</button>',
  props: ['isHidden'],
  methods: {
    enableSave() {
      this.$emit('change-hidden', !this.isHidden);
    }
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    UserData
  },
  data: {
    isHidden: true
  },
  methods: {
    onChangeHidden(e) {
      this.isHidden = e;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  isHidden : {{ isHidden }}
  <user-data :is-hidden="isHidden" v-on:change-hidden="onChangeHidden" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [ref attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) to access a child component.

You would have to add `ref="Something"` in `<UserData>`, and access the component using `this.$refs.Something`

// Profile.vue

```
<UserData
v-bind:user_billing="user_billing"
v-bind:user_profile="user_profile"
ref="UserData"
>
</UserData>
...
 data: function () {
      return {
        isHidden: true,
    }
}
```

// UserData.vue

```
<template>
  <form v-on:change="enableSave()"
...
methods: {
 enableSave(){
    this.$refs.UserData.isHidden = false
 }
}
```